# Filter dataframe using the most recent datetime entry on a 5 minute interval

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr

I've updated this reproducible example since I realized my first did not quite illustrate the problem I ran into.

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1)
start <- mdy_hms("11-20-2023 00:00:00")
int <- 61
end <- start + as.difftime(2, units = "hours")

dt <- seq(from = start, to = end, by = int)

time <- sample(dt, 30)

value <- sample(1:10,30, replace = TRUE)

tb <- tibble(time,value) %>% arrange(time)
```

output

```
tb %>% head(10)

# A tibble: 10 × 2
   time                value
   <dttm>              <int>
 1 2023-11-20 00:00:00    10
 2 2023-11-20 00:06:00    10
 3 2023-11-20 00:13:00    10
 4 2023-11-20 00:20:00     9
 5 2023-11-20 00:32:00     3
 6 2023-11-20 00:33:00     6
 7 2023-11-20 00:36:00     6
 8 2023-11-20 00:38:00    10
 9 2023-11-20 00:42:00     4
10 2023-11-20 00:43:00     6
```

I want to filter this dataframe to only keep the most recent entry every 5 minutes. So for example here the row 1 is both the the most recent to 00:00:00 and 00:05:00. Row 2 is most recent to 00:10:00. Row 5 should be dropped since it is after 00:30:00 but row 6 is closer to 00:35:00.

As an example of something I tried was rounding the minutes to the nearest 5.

```
tb %>%
+   mutate(mins = round(minute(time)/5)*5) %>% head(10)
# A tibble: 10 × 3
   time                value  mins
   <dttm>              <int> <dbl>
 1 2023-11-20 00:00:00    10     0
 2 2023-11-20 00:06:00    10     5
 3 2023-11-20 00:13:00    10    15
 4 2023-11-20 00:20:00     9    20
 5 2023-11-20 00:32:00     3    30
 6 2023-11-20 00:33:00     6    35
 7 2023-11-20 00:36:00     6    35
 8 2023-11-20 00:38:00    10    40
 9 2023-11-20 00:42:00     4    40
10 2023-11-20 00:43:00     6    45
```

However row 4 violates my condition, 00:32:00 comes after 00:30:00. Also row 2 violates my condition since at 00:05:00 row 2 which has time 00:06:00 has not happened yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Updated for added constraint and data.)*

I think we can do a "rolling join" on this.

```r
times <- tibble(
  fiveminute = seq(floor_date(min(tb$time), unit = "5 mins"),
                   ceiling_date(max(tb$time), unit = "5 mins"),
                   by = "5 mins"))
left_join(times, tb, join_by(fiveminute >= time), multiple = "last")
# # A tibble: 25 × 3
#    fiveminute          time                value
#    <dttm>              <dttm>              <int>
#  1 2023-11-20 00:00:00 2023-11-20 00:00:00    10
#  2 2023-11-20 00:05:00 2023-11-20 00:00:00    10
#  3 2023-11-20 00:10:00 2023-11-20 00:06:00    10
#  4 2023-11-20 00:15:00 2023-11-20 00:13:00    10
#  5 2023-11-20 00:20:00 2023-11-20 00:20:00     9
#  6 2023-11-20 00:25:00 2023-11-20 00:20:00     9
#  7 2023-11-20 00:30:00 2023-11-20 00:20:00     9
#  8 2023-11-20 00:35:00 2023-11-20 00:33:00     6
#  9 2023-11-20 00:40:00 2023-11-20 00:38:00    10
# 10 2023-11-20 00:45:00 2023-11-20 00:43:00     6
# # ℹ 15 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

---

Data

```r
tb <- structure(list(time = structure(c(1700438400, 1700438760, 1700439180, 1700439600, 1700440320, 1700440380, 1700440560, 1700440680, 1700440920, 1700440980, 1700441400, 1700441580, 1700441880, 1700442420, 1700442720, 1700442780, 1700443080, 1700443260, 1700443380, 1700443440, 1700443560, 1700443680, 1700444160, 1700444280, 1700444340, 1700444460, 1700444700, 1700444880, 1700445360, 1700445600), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), value = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 10L, 4L, 6L, 6L,  8L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 9L, 3L, 8L, 4L, 8L, 9L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 10L, 2L, 3L)), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Issue was on my end, I updated the question to match properly. Your solution works, thanks.

Comment: It happens to me often when I setup `set.seed` and then keep testing the "reproducible code" but forget to always include that first line. No big deal, it wasn't critical this time since your description was clear enough. Glad it helped!

Comment: This actually isn't quite what I was looking for. round_date() rounds to the nearest 5 minute interval, but if my most recent time to XX:X5:00 is XX:X1:XX then it rounds this down to 00:00:00. I had a similar issue when I tried extracting minutes and rounding them.

Comment: I see, could you please update your sample data to specifically highlight this phenomenom?

Comment: I've updated the question with a new example and more detail, sorry about that.

Comment: See my edit. No worries, often it's a spiraling process.

Answer (score 0):

Using floor_date from the lubridate package, we can creat a new column to group the time values into time intervals:

```
tb <- tb %>%
  mutate(interval = floor_date(time, "5 minutes"))

> tb %>% head(10)

# A tibble: 10 × 3
   time                value interval           
   <dttm>              <int> <dttm>             
 1 2023-11-20 00:01:03     7 2023-11-20 00:00:00
 2 2023-11-20 00:01:24    10 2023-11-20 00:00:00
 3 2023-11-20 00:01:48     4 2023-11-20 00:00:00
 4 2023-11-20 00:01:57     3 2023-11-20 00:00:00
 5 2023-11-20 00:04:09     1 2023-11-20 00:00:00
 6 2023-11-20 00:04:15     3 2023-11-20 00:00:00
 7 2023-11-20 00:12:21     9 2023-11-20 00:10:00
 8 2023-11-20 00:13:27     2 2023-11-20 00:10:00
 9 2023-11-20 00:14:18     9 2023-11-20 00:10:00
10 2023-11-20 00:15:45     2 2023-11-20 00:15:00
```

Then filter the most recent time within each interval:

```
tb <- tb %>%
  group_by(interval) %>%
  filter(time == max(time)) %>%
  ungroup()


# A tibble: 10 × 3
# Groups:   interval [10]
   time                value interval           
   <dttm>              <int> <dttm>             
 1 2023-11-20 00:04:15     3 2023-11-20 00:00:00
 2 2023-11-20 00:14:18     9 2023-11-20 00:10:00
 3 2023-11-20 00:18:24     3 2023-11-20 00:15:00
 4 2023-11-20 00:24:12     9 2023-11-20 00:20:00
 5 2023-11-20 00:29:48     7 2023-11-20 00:25:00
 6 2023-11-20 00:33:54     1 2023-11-20 00:30:00
 7 2023-11-20 00:36:36     8 2023-11-20 00:35:00
 8 2023-11-20 00:43:51     7 2023-11-20 00:40:00
 9 2023-11-20 00:49:45     9 2023-11-20 00:45:00
10 2023-11-20 00:53:42     2 2023-11-20 00:50:00
```